# How to output values from data blocks in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

In Terraform it is possible to output values from self created **resource**s.

Now I want to output values from resources that are fetched via **data** block.
I could not find any information on that.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same way. For example, I defined the data source `aws_vpc`

```
data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  tags {
    Name = "development"
  }
}
```

You can use it in output as below

```
output "vpic_id" {
  value = "${data.aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
}
```

Comment: I was missing the "data"-keyword here. Works now.